# How to access Datasources and Drivers in Wildfly 27 on Linux CentOS 8

Tags: mysql, linux

I installed Wildfly 27 on Linux CentOS 8, apparently the installation was successful, my objective is the MySQL database, so following Red Hat Administration and Configuration Guide I created the directory `WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql` `/main` and in that directory I downloaded `mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar` and created the `module.xml` file, I created a user in wildfly.

When opening wildfly in my browser `IpAddress:9990` I inform my user when requested and The HAL Management Console opens, I click on Configuration, Subsystems and the Datasources and Drivers option, but datasources and drivers does not open so I can continue the mysql installation process. Below I inform the actions taken.

Directory contents:

```
ls /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main 
module.xml mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar
```

Installation:

```
ls -l /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com total 0 
drwxr-xr-x. 4 wildfly wildfly 28 Dec 15 2022 amazon 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 18 Dec 15 2022 carrotsearch 
drwxr-xr-x. 4 wildfly wildfly 38 Dec 15 2022 fasterxml 
drwxr-xr-x. 4 wildfly wildfly 34 Dec 15 2022 github 
drwxr-xr-x. 5 wildfly wildfly 47 Dec 15 2022 google 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 22 Dec 15 2022 googlecode 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 16 Dec 15 2022 h2database 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 19 Dec 15 2022 ibm 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 19 Dec 15 2022 microsoft 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 18 Dec 26 09:36 mysql 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 29 Dec 15 2022 nimbusds 
drwxr-xr-x. 3 wildfly wildfly 21 Dec 15 2022 squareup 
drwxr-xr-x. 4 wildfly wildfly 33 Dec 15 2022 sun
```

module.xml content:

```
<module name="com.mysql" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9"> 
<resources> 
          <resource-root path="mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar"/>
</resources> 
<dependencies> 
          <module name="javax.api"/> 
          <module name="javax.transactio.api"/> 
</dependencies> 
</module>
```

In the `standalone.xml` default we have `h2database` defined as sample, neither this datasource and driver was showed before that I include my definitions of MySQL. My objective is the MySQL database.